# Convert Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting array in loop.

```
Array
(
     [name] => Birthday
 )

Array
(
    [name] => Marriage Anniversary
)
```

Now i want to make dynamic in following format.How can i do this ?

```
return [['value' => 'birthday1', 'label' => __('Birthday1')], ['value' => 'wedding_anniversary', 'label' => __('Marriage Anniversery')]];
```

Comment: how are we supposed to know the dynamic values `birthday1`, `wedding_anniversary`? Are these present in the looped array? Also, please show your loop code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a possible approach:

```
<?php
$input = [
    ['name' => 'Birthday'],
    ['name' => 'Marriage Anniversary']
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($set) use (&$output) {
    $entry = $set['name'];
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($entry));
    $label = $entry;
    $output[] = [
        'value' => $value,
        'label' => $label
    ];
});
print_r($output);
```

The output of the above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => birthday
            [label] => Birthday
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => marriage_anniversary
            [label] => Marriage Anniversary
        )

)
```

---

Your question is a bit unclear about that number you suggest trailing one of the values ("birthday1")... If you *really* need some sort of counter for the occurrences of values, then here is a modified version of above code:

```
<?php
$input = [
    ['name' => 'Birthday'],
    ['name' => 'Marriage Anniversary'],
    ['name' => 'Birthday']
];
$output = [];
$catalog = [];
array_walk($input, function($set) use (&$catalog, &$output) {
    $entry = $set['name'];
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($entry));
    $catalog[$value] = isset($catalog[$value]) ? ++$catalog[$value] : 1;

    $label = $entry;
    $output[] = [
        'value' => $value . $catalog[$value],
        'label' => $label
    ];
});
print_r($output);
```

The modified output would obviously be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => birthday1
            [label] => Birthday
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => marriage_anniversary1
            [label] => Marriage Anniversary
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => birthday2
            [label] => Birthday
        )

)
```